# Last Commit time from Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr

How can I Find the last commit time from Apache Solr. And last commit time is same as last modifed date?
As with the use of LukeRequestHandler we can get the Last Modified Date-

```
http://localhost:8180/solr/ad

<date name="lastModified">2011-10-11T07</date>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.